# How to force DHCP server to provide a new IP?

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server

I am using DHCP option 50 (client is an embedded device running eCos RTOS) to request a specific IP from the DHCP server (DHCP server is a built-in one with Windows 2003 server).

First DHCP client request an IP a.b.c.d and server assigns it. Then if I request another IP immediately (say a.b.c.e) the server will not assign the second IP. Instead it is again assigning the first IP itself.

It seems to me like if I ask for another address before the lease expires, it will not assign another IP.

Is it possible to ask the server a new IP, even if the lease has not expired yet?

Comment: Well given the behaviour is going to be very dependant on the DHCP Server in use, you should probably give us some information about what software that is.

Comment: @fukawi2 : Question updated with the DHCP server information.

Comment: Related to: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17401/how-can-i-release-and-renew-my-dhcp-lease-from-terminal?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this would be to change the MAC address of your client.  No idea what OS your using but on most modern Linux distros `ip link set address <NEW-MAC> dev <Interface>` will do the job.

If you doing this  repeatedly ensure your dhcp server has short leases and/or a large pool of IPs. When you change your MAC address the lease will stay until it expires, so if your not careful you will exhaust the servers address pool